# Find the smallest number in an array and the position it is

Tags: c++, c, arrays

i have this code, and i want to find the smallest number and in which position it is in an array 3x3,How do i do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
    int A[3][3];
  int i,j;
  int min;
min=0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)    
{
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        if(A[i][j]>=min)
            min=A[i][j];
    }
    printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n",min);
}
```

}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't shown any attempt to do your homework for yourself.

Comment: no,its not a homework,,im just learnig,and cant find any similar on the internet

Comment: What is it specifically that you are having difficulty with? The algorithm, converting the algorithm to code, both, or something else? The algorithm is simple. Record the first array element as the current smallest. Go through each array element. If it is smaller than the current smallest then record it as the smallest. After going through all the elements you have your answer.

Comment: i changed the code,,i found the smalest number but ,for every row,,i want to find the smallest number in these 3 rows and the position its in

Comment: Ok, but now you have changed your question. Either ask a new question or update your question description to reflect what it is you really want an answer for. As it is, your code already does what your question asks for.

Comment: Your code finds the max number, not the min.  It also fails when all the numbers are negative.

Comment: yep,i know that ,but this guy did it and used some new things i didnt know and im searching about these now

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < limits.h >

int main() {
    int A[3][3];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int min = INT_MAX, y = -1, x = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (A[i][j] < min) {
                min = A[i][j];
                y = i;
                x = j;
            }

            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Minimum is %d, located at %d, %d\n", min, y, x);
}
```

Comment: please include explanation, that how it solve the problem? what was wrong with the snippet in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot!!                 int min = INT_MAX, y = -1, x = -1;                                               this is what i didnt know and how its working

Comment: @christos, have you considered to accept this answer?

Comment: This code fails should every `A[i][j]==INT_MAX` as `x,y` needlessly retains the value of `-1`.  Suggest `if (A[i][j] < min) {` --> `if (A[i][j] <= min) {`